# Computing expected value of multinomial variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

We consider a two-dimensional dicrete probability distribution on $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ with $|\mathcal{X}|\cdot |\mathcal{Y}| = r \cdot q$ distinct values with corresponding probabilities $p = (p(x, y))_{x \in \mathcal{X}, y \in \mathcal{Y}}$. Then we generate $n$ independent observations $(X_i, Y_i)$ from this distribution. We summarize them in a matrix $M = (M(x,y))_{x \in \mathcal{X}, y \in \mathcal{Y}}$, where $M(x, y)$ is a number of observations that equals $(x,y)$: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{I}(X_i=x, Y_i=y)$. Thus $M$ has a multinomial distribution $Mult(n, p)$ with a two-dimensional structure. If we want to summarize counts in a row or a column, we write $M(x) = \sum_y M(x, y)$ and $M(y) = \sum_x M(x, y)$ respectively.

What I want to do is to compute expected value of expressions including $M(x,y)$, $M(x)$ and $M(y)$ for example $\mathbb{E} M^2(x)$ or more complicated such as $\mathbb{E} (M^2(x)M(x, y))$.

When $r=q=2$ I know how to do it. For example for $\mathbb{E} M^2(x=1)$ it can be done like this:

```
Nx1 = MultinomialDistribution[n, {Subscript[p, 11], Subscript[p, 12], Subscript[p, 21], Subscript[p, 22]}]
ENx1 = Expectation[(a + c)^2, {a, b, c, d} \[Distributed] Nx1]
```

but I don't know how to do it without having $r$ and $q$ given. Is it possible? And is it possible to obtain a result as a vector $(\mathbb{E} M^2(x))_{x \in \mathcal{X}}$?

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make a lot of sense. You seem to want to take expectations of abstract MultinomialDistributions with an arbitrary dimension r*q. This is not possible.

Comment: @flinty Does it mean that it is impossible to compute $\mathbb{E} M$, where $M \sim Mult(n, (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_q))$ without setting value of $q$?

Comment: You cannot do it in Mathematica with `Expection` and `MultinomialDistribution` without having a set number of dimensions $q$. Only when the expectation is trivial and you don't mix variables in $M$ can you generalize to $q$ dimensions.